# Preventing shell from exiting when set -e is turned on?

Tags: bash, command-substitution, error-handling, set

I have `set -e` turned on for my script. The only thing is there is one command here that I don't want causing the script to exit if it fails, but I want everything else to do that. How can I keep `set -e` on, and not have my script exit when an error code is thrown?

script in question:

```
native=$(pacman -Qenq -)
```

If stdin has a non-native package name an error code gets written to stdin.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the issue you're having is. Empty strings are not unset and the code you have should work fine.

Comment: `pacman -Qenq -` is run with `stdin` holding a foreign package `native` ends up being unset.

Comment: No it doesn't, because you set it. Something else is going on.

Comment: ... and your `-x` output shows it being set (to an empty string, but set).

Comment: Alright, it's having `set -e` turned on for the script.

Comment: `native=$(pacman -Qenq -) && : cancel set -e` or `native=$(pacman -Qenq -) || : ignore error completely`

Comment: I ended up using `native=$(pacman -Qenq -) || true`

What is the advantage / difference of the two example commands you showed?

Comment: The difference will be the value of `$?` afterwards. See [Which is more idiomatic in a bash script: \`|| true\` or \`|| :\`?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/78411)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`set -e` aka `set -o errexit` doesn't apply to commands that are parts of conditions like in:

```
if cmd; do
until cmd; do
while cmd; do
cmd || whatever
cmd && whatever
```

That also applies to the `ERR` trap for shells supporting it.

So, an idiomatic way to ignore the failure of a command is with:

```
cmd || : errors ignored
```

Or just:

```
cmd || true
cmd || :
```

That cancels `set -e` for that `cmd` invocation and also sets `$?` to 0 (to that of `:`/`true` when `cmd`  fails)

```
cmd && true
ret=$?
```

Also cancels `set -e` but preserves the exit status of `cmd`.

Comment: So what's the difference between the value of `$?` between `cmd || true` and `cmd || :`?

Comment: @ZeroPhase, like I said, after `cmd || :`, `$?` is 0. After `cmd && :`, `$?` is the exit status of `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

```
> var=
> : ${var:=foo}
> echo "$var"
foo
```

Comment: A tiny bit of explanation would be nice. For example, not everybody knows the `:` command.